# SignalR client running a long processor

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I would like to build a customer billing tool using signalR.
I am unsure if SignalR is the correct technology really, I currently use a scheduled service that runs twice a day.

I would like to send a request to connected clients to perform a billing routine anytime I want. The client will run a number of activities (generate reports, call some stored procedures etc... which can take up to 5 minutes to complete.

I have built a simple system but I am concerned about the long running task on the client. Whilst the long process is running the client is unable to retrieve other requests from the server, once the long task is complete all the requests appear.

Is there any way to just ignore requests on the client until the long task is complete? Or a better way to handle the requests? Maybe SignalR isn’t the best approach.

Comment: Show some code with how you are requesting to get some help. You don't have to make requests async. You can submit a request back to the server and let it do it's job. You could update the user with the status of the job periodically. SignalR is just fine for making requests and providing real time updates back to your client/UI.

Comment: It’s the client that needs to do the work

Comment: With your client doing the work you will probably want to look into creating a web worker. Your UI by itself is single threaded, so when it's busy you can't do anything else really. Web workers solve that by letting you offload work locally and keep your UI available and able to process requests.

Comment: Frank, its a windows service that runs on the client, no UI